# CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Path with spaces can not find file

Tags: vbscript, wsh, hta, wscript.shell

I am receiving a error when running a `WScript.Shell` `Run` with a path that has a spaces in it.

I've tried several different variations that result in the same error.

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """Program Files\scripts\exe\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -realtime -d c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 264"" ", 0, True
```

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Program Files\scripts\exe\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -realtime -d c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 264", 0, True
```

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "'Program Files\scripts\exe\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -realtime -d c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 264'", 0, True
```

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("Program Files\scripts\exe\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -realtime -d c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 264", 0, True)
```

I understand the space in the path is causing an error, I just cant wrap my head around wrapping with quotes correctly.

Comment: You're calling a relative path (starting with `Program Files\scripts\...`. Try to fully qualify the path by prefixing `C:\ ` (if this is your drive). Also you would have to use this syntax `"""Program Files\scripts\exe\PsExec64.exe"" -accepteula -realtime -d c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 264", 0, True"`

Comment: The last `"` in my comment has to be removed. Unfortunately I cant remove it any more.

Comment: UGH :| You're a God, thank you. I've been looking at this for hours and you fixed it in minutes. I always feel dumb posting here because it's usually something so stupid.

Comment: Working with quotes is always tricky. In almost all my vbscripts I include a function to double-quote variables. As long as you propertly identify them, it can be of help. `Function dq(ByVal s)
 dg = Chr(34) & s & Chr(34)
End Function` (Code in comments looks rubbish, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the drive letter, e.g. c:\program files